# Running a batch file in git shell

Tags: git, powershell, windows-7, batch-file

Under Windows 7 I have a batch file for checking the status of some repos and outputting the returns to a file (with standard powershell issued git commands).

This works fine when launched from git shell, my question is how can I do this without launching git shell first?

So I want to be able to enter in a standard prompt or in a runnable batch file a command / commands which will launch a given batch file in git shell.

Comment: A question: What version of git for windows have you got? I was struggling with installing msys Git for win (7) but some commands took ages to complete... Now got git only via cygwin.

Comment: I have 1.7.11.rc1.6953.gf229a20 - Was installed with the new GitHub windows application

Comment: Can you do simple git commands from Powershell?  In other words, is the git shell required to do anything with git?  If you can access git from Powershell, then you could rewrite your batch file as a powershell script.  Alternatively, you should be able to run your batch file from Powershell, unless it sets env vars (if so, search "Invoke-CmdScript" on Google).

Comment: I cannot do git commands from Powershell and I dont want to have to open powershell before running a batch file. The objective is to be able to issue a set of git commands in git shell with a single action

Comment: So you want to run a set of git commands without using any kind of shell. If thats what you want then sorry its impossible. Be more specific with your questions please. I am unable to understand anything from your question.

Comment: Everyone else has @Learath2... the point is not to run git commands without a shell, but to run git commands from a batch file or from the standard command prompt in a single action (ie not from git shell or powershell)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you consider what **[`git-cmd.bat`](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/blob/devel/git-cmd.bat)** does, all you need to do is to set the right variable `%PATH%` before your git commands in your script:

If you don't, here is what you would see:

```
C:\Users\VonC>git --version
'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I have uncompressed the [latest portable version of msysgit](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/downloads/list).

Put anywhere a `test.bat` script (so no powershell involved there) with the following content:

```
@setlocal

@set git_install_root="C:\Users\VonC\prg\PortableGit-1.7.11-preview20120620"
@set PATH=%git_install_root%\bin;%git_install_root%\mingw\bin;%git_install_root%\cmd;%PATH%

@if not exist "%HOME%" @set HOME=%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%
@if not exist "%HOME%" @set HOME=%USERPROFILE%

@set PLINK_PROTOCOL=ssh

REM here is the specific git commands of your script

git --version
echo %HOME%
git config --global --list
```

Make sure `HOME` is correctly set, because Git will look for your global git config there.

The result will give you:

```
C:\Users\VonC>cd prog\git

C:\Users\VonC\prog\git>s.bat

C:\Users\VonC\prog\git>git --version
git version 1.7.11.msysgit.0

C:\Users\VonC\prog\git>echo C:\Users\VonC
C:\Users\VonC

C:\Users\VonC\prog\git>git config --global --list
user.name=VonC
```

Note: that same script would work perfectly from a powershell session.

Comment: Thanks @VonC, this looks promising, will test this on Wed.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your git executable is just not accessible for command line use.

Just add `c:\Users\[your_login]\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_[hash]\bin` (or `c:\Users\[your_login]\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_[hash]\cmd`) to your Path variable. Replacing `[your_login]` and `[hash]` with actual data.

But I believe the location of files will change from version to version, so if you're heavy git user, consider installing [msysGit](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/). It will add its executable to the system path automatically (corresponding option available during setup).

Even more, there is the project called [mysysGit-UTF8](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit-utf8/) claiming that they have full UTF-8 support on Windows. I didn't notice the difference, through.

Comment: If you don't choose the option to add it to syspath It won't add it